# tab button to change focus from one text field to other using bluetooth keyboard on iPad

Tags: ios

I have a module to be developed where i need to tab on my form textfields using bluetooth keyboard. But it doesn't seem to work. the method textfieldshouldbeginEditing gets called multiple times as many times as the number of text fields on the xib. Can you please help as to how to change the responder once i get the tag of selected field. I have my text fields in an array. tried using that but it continuously loops in that method.

Answer (score 1):

Dealing with tabs within your views is a non-trivial task.  At a high level, UIKit will check every visible field within the view once to determine which fields could be tabbed into, then it will check the "next" field a second time.  You will need to keep track of which fields have been checked, and what order you want the tab to proceed in if you want to deal with this issue.

Please see [this blog post](https://weaklyreferenced.wordpress.com/2012/11/13/responding-to-the-tab-and-shift-tab-keys-on-ios-5-ios-6-with-an-external-keyboard/comment-page-1/) for a great explanation.